# How to extend a homeomorphism defined on a corner piece of a rectangle to the full rectangle?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Say we have a rectangle $R=[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and consider the line segment connecting the points $(1,0)$ and $(.9,1)$.  This forms what I am referring to as an upper right corner piece $C$ of the rectangle.

Say I have a homeomorphism $h$ defined on $C$; are there some extension theorems that say I can extend $h$ onto all of $R$ in such a way that the extension becomes the identity on $R \backslash C$ fairly "quickly" (say, within an $\epsilon$ amount of space to the left of the line segment)?

Comment: Did you want $R\setminus C$ in place of $R^c?$

Comment: Yes, I will edit that.

Comment: Do you need the extension to be a homeomorphism on $R?$

Comment: Yes, I need it to be a homeomorphism on $R$.

Comment: So $h$ is a homeomorphism of $C$ onto $C$? And should the extension then be a homeomorphism of $R$ onto $R$?

Comment: Yes, and let me say, I'm sorry that these details were not included.

Comment: Then I would say there need not be one unless there are further hidden details. For example, the hypotenuse of $C$ could be mapped by $h$ to the segment $\{1\} \times [0,1].$

Comment: Do you think if we required that the hypotenuse of $C$ map to itself (allowing for rearrangement of points), that the extension would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any specific theorems, but this should be possible in the following sense, assume that we have a rectangle made of very stretchy rubber, then any homeomorphism of C is just a continuous deformation of it, now glue the rubber rectangle to the table except for where C is and for an $\epsilon$ distance around it (assuming some given metric for R), then we can grab C and lift it up off the table, this will stretch the rubber around it but everything glued down will still be exactly where it was, now we apply $h$ to C (say we elongate it and bend it a bit), this will also change the parts of R that weren't glued down, but again all the rest of R is exactly where it was. We can now define this resulting configuration of the rubber sheet as our extension of $h$ to R, and it is the identity on all of R except to within an $\epsilon$ distance of C (in the original metric on R before the transformation).

Note that there are some technicalities here, we must assume we are dealing with the subspace topology on C inherited from R. Also we must be careful by what we mean by 'within' an $\epsilon$ distance of C since we actually had to stretch parts of the rubber sheet not in C in order to have the transformed C still continuously joined to the rubber sheet, this is why I specified it is within an $\epsilon$ distance w.r.t the original metric on R and $\textbf{before}$ the transformation is applied. Always remember that topology on it's own cares not for distance, only form and shape.